# Crashlytics not uploading symbols in "Archive" mode

Tags: ios, release, archive, crashlytics

I managed to setup Crashlytics for an iOS app

1. Added `./Crashlytics.framework/run <uuid>` as a post build step
2. Then my code uses `[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:<uuid>` at startup.

So far it works works.

But since I have a script that changes the `CFBundleVersion` automatically for every single build, I decided to disable Crashlytics for debug builds, to avoid being spammed by development versions.

I followed these [guidlines](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/118559-can-i-make-the-dsym-uploading-only-on-release-build) from the help pages, and changed my script to

```
releaseConfig="Release"
if [ "$releaseConfig" = "${CONFIGURATION}" ]; then   
    echo "Running Crashlytics"
    ./Crashlytics.framework/run {your_api_key_here}
fi
```

It works. The script only runs only when I use the "Archive" mode of Xcode 5, which is doing release builds.

However, unless I make a normal "Build", the version I archived does not appear in the Crashlytics dashboard, even when I make it crash with `[Crashlytics crash]` and wait for hours... But if I make a normal "Build" with the same `CFBundleVersion`, then suddenly my build appears in the dashboard, with all the crashes against the release build. (I know because I report the fact it's a release build with custom keys).

What so different between the "Archive" and "Build" mode? Is this a bug? Has any body managed to make a similar setup work with Crashlytics? What am I missing here?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but FYI, the scheme determines the configuration that gets built when archiving.  Check your scheme and make sure it's building the "Release" configuration.